# Select a image from the gallery and show it in another Activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I am making an android application in which i have to select image from gallery by clicking a button and then display it in another activity with two text fields, the problem is i am able to open the gallery and select image from it but i am not able to display image in another activity...
here is my code...
`PictureOptions.java`

```
public void buttonGalleryOpen(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     Bitmap selectedphoto   = null;

     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

         Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
         String [] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
         Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
         cursor.moveToFirst();   
         int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
         String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
         selectedphoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
         cursor.close();
         Intent intent = new Intent(PictureOptions.this,ShowImage.class);
         intent.putExtra("data", selectedphoto);
         startActivity(intent);
     }
```

`PictureOptions.xml`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonGalleryOpen"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.34"
    android:onClick="buttonGalleryOpen"
    android:text="@string/button_gallery_open" />
```

`ShowImage.java`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_image);
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageShow);
    Bitmap selectedphoto  =(Bitmap)this.getIntent().getParcelableExtra("data");
    imageview.setImageBitmap(selectedphoto);
}
```

`ShowImage.xml`

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageShow"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp" />
```

All things are working fine and second activity(ShowImage) is also opening except that no iamge is displying....dont know why..?HELP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in your code does not make sense:

```
intent.putExtra("data", "selectedphoto");
```

You are adding here string "selectedphoto" which is in no way connected to selectedphoto variable you initialised earlier. You could put your bitmap to intent extra as byte array but this is inefficient, especially when the image is large.

Instead of passing bitmap to ShowImage activity, pass your URI and then retrieve actual bitmap in ShowImage activity exactly as you do now in your PictureOptions activity.

```
intent.setData( uri );
```

In your ShowImage activity do:

```
URI imageUri = getIntent().getData();
```

Comment: i have edited it, but it doesnt showing image even now and is redirecting to first activity... help me

Comment: look at the logs, maybe image is too large - there is a limit in how large a parcel can be. I strongly recommend you pass only URI to your ShowImage activity.

Comment: Common, did you even try to search? Anyway, I have modified my answer.

Comment: The method putData(Uri) is undefined for the type Intent(Error)

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in method name, setData is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yo have a typo in  `intent.putExtra("data", "selectedphoto");`, you are passing a String not the bitmap. Change it in

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(PictureOptions.this,ShowImage.class);
 intent.putExtra("data", selectedphoto);
 startActivity(intent);
```

removing the double quote from `selectedphoto`

Comment: i have done the changes but now second activity is not even opening...it is redirected to the first activity... why?

Comment: uhm does the logcat say something?

Comment: it says...FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!
Tag: Java Binder

Comment: it is not related. Can you print the value of filePath?

Comment: no error is present in the code..... i think there is a problem related to size of image...any help from your side?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void selectImage() {
    final CharSequence[] items = { "Photo Library", "Camera", "Cancel" };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Select");
    Utils.hideSoftKeyboard(getActivity());
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (items[item].equals("Camera")) {

                  // camera intent

            } else if (items[item].equals("Photo Library")) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(
                            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                            SELECT_FILE);

            } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}



@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

          if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            String tempPath = getPath(selectedImageUri, getActivity());

            BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempPath, btmapOptions);
            resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,
                    (int) (bitmap.getWidth() * 0.8),
                    (int) (bitmap.getHeight() * 0.8), true);

            profileEditImageView.setImageBitmap(resized);

     }
    }
   }


public String getPath(Uri uri, Activity activity) {
    String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = activity
            .managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```